# Keystore file not found

Tags: android

I imported a project(made by someone else) from GitHub and tried to run it on my Android Studio but it gives me the message "Keystore file singed.jks not found for config 'sign'

I tried to copy and use my keystore file but it does not work.

Could someone please help me out?

Comment: Post build.gradle please.

Comment: Are you sure you placed it at the location where it is expecting? Also post the error message and the file it references in that message.

Comment: Add a few more details like the exact error message and if all the references are added or not and so on...

Comment: The project is https://github.com/stefankmitph/kint

Comment: @JohnLee put that into your question click on the "edit" think below your question). It's unreadable in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your application there is "signed.jks" file not found and it's not in given path if you have it just put it's path correctly.

Otherwise just **remove** below line from **app module defaultConfig bracket** and remove debug bracket also

```
signingConfig signingConfigs.sign
```

Above line of code when you remove then this code would run in debug mode. But whenever you need to upload your APK in Play store that time you must make it signed APK using same keystore file.

Comment: Your signed.jks file also exist inside your previous commit please download from there and keep it inside any where in you computer and give proper path,or just keep it inside your project and just write this code "storeFile file('signed.jks')" instead of "storeFile file('../signed.jks')".

Comment: thank you very much! I found the file and I managed to run the app on virtual Machine. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnLee,
Welcome brother

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem and took me almost 2-3 hours to figure out what went wrong!

What I figured out was ->

> Syntax of `keystore.properties` is OS specific

```
//in ubuntu
storeFile=keystore_filepath_relative_to_.../app/
storePassword=password
keyAlias=key_alias
keyPassword=key_password


//in windows
storeFile=file('keystore_absolute_filepath')
storePassword='password'
keyAlias='key_alias'
keyPassword='key_password'

//Notice the difference in single quotes and file paths
```

> And `build.gradle` should look like this

```
....
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("keystore.properties")
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
...
android {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        }
        stageBuild {
            ...
        }
        debug {
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
    buildTypes {
    release {
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
    debug {
        //applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        debuggable true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
    staging {
        debuggable true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.stageBuild
    }
}
```

Added this to my github gist [build.gradle(Module:app)](https://gist.github.com/aap01/92e02d3d88b6fe155631ef071a68f463)